# jQuery Keypad / Primefaces keyboard re-map spacebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, keyboard, keyboard-events

I face issue with jQuery Keypad / Primefaces keyboard - I try to re-map default spacebar button to input hex value '32' instead of '160'. Because when I type "space" from my phisical keyboard then it gives different value (32) then from virtual one (160)

Any solutions? Because I try to avoid writting my own component.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like in his source code for US Keyboards he makes spacebar 160 for some reason: https://github.com/kbwood/keypad/blob/master/src/js/jquery.keypad.js But it looks like you can override the regional value for spaceBarText.

Comment: You could always report an issue on his github page too: https://github.com/kbwood/keypad/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone struggle with same problem.

I have fix it by override _generateHTML function inside keyboard.js from Primefaces 6.1 . For next version it will be configurable, but for this I will change (line 717):

```
(keys[j] == this.SPACE_BAR ? '&nbsp;' :
(keys[j] == ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : keys[j]))))))) + '</button>'));
```

To:

```
(keys[j] == this.SPACE_BAR ? ' ' : keys[j])))))) + '</button>'));
```

And for me works fine.